# iPhone - how to submit an application for a client

Tags: iphone, upload

I've written an iPhone application for a client. He has purchased a single developer certificate as I have, and authorized me to do whatever needs to be done to submit the application to the app store.

Will there be any problem creating a code signing identity on my system for the client?

I realize the question is kind of vague - basically, is it do-able from my system without fouling up my own applications? If so, what do I have to do differently than if I were uploading my own application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to log in to the client's developer account and create a certificate there, using your existing (or create a new) Certificate Signing Request (which is created using Keychain Access and your private key, or create a new private key for this purpose).

Then download that certificate and add it to your keychain.  You'll then need to generate the appropriate Distribution profile (in the client's account) using the certificate you just created. Download that profile and use that to sign your build. Now you have a build signed as your client that you can upload to iTunes Connect once the app is created there and you are ready to upload the binary.

I have done this for 2 clients successfully.